# redirect to spring mvc controller without opening a page

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send some data back to my application without navigating away from the existing page.  I would rather not reload the current page.

The application already has a download option which works in the way I want it to...  The button works as follows

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='/DownloadEndpoint?params'">Download</button>
```

This goes to an endpoint which downloads a csv file and leaves the current page as is.

The controller has a void return parameter

```
RequestMapping(value = "/DownloadEndpoint")
public void csvDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute(MODEL_ATTR_NAME) FacetedSearchRequestBean searchRequestBean, @PathVariable(value = PERSON_ID) String personId) throws IOException {
```

and the ResponseHeader is edited to got to csv

```
protected void setCsvResponseHeaders(HttpServletResponse response, final String cvsSearchType) {
    response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=utf-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.csv");
}
```

When I try to do this for my own purposes with a different controller, without editing the response header I get a blank page

This is my button in the jsp (pretty much a copy)

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/FeedBack/Test'">Ok</button>
```

Passing to this controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Test")
public void popUpTest(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws InterruptedException 
{
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

This works to the extent that control is sent to the Test controller but instead of leaving the current page in the browser the browser displays an empty screen.

Is there a way to edit the response header to not go anywhere or do anything so that I can perform my application code and and leave the browser on the calling page without refreshing it in any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with

```
javascript:window.location
```

Because this change the location of your browser to a different page. You can make an ajax call instead.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //do something
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "your url here", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If you use jQuery it's easier.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "url",
            success: function( response ){
                //do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: Many thanks for that.  if you have a minute, how would you do it with jQuery ? thanks again.